# QEMU Guest Agent for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: kvm, qemu, libvirt

I've been looking for the QEMU Guest Agent for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. It seems like the Guest Agent is included in the official Repository from Ubuntu 14.04 and up (http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/qemu-guest-agent).

Is there a way to get the Guest Agent running in 12.04?

**Update** Compiling and/or installing qemu-guest-agent from the Trusty Repos seems to be the solution. While testing different VMs I noticed that the hosts have different OS versions (one with Precise/KVM and the other with Trusty/Spice). So my problem seems to be related to the combination of host and guest OSes. I have opened another question for this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to download the agent from http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/qemu-guest-agent (using the `amd64` or `i386` links in the "Download" table) and install it manually using `sudo dpkg -i`. The dependencies are satisfied in 12.04 so it should install without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easiest to download the source and recompile it:

```
cat > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/trusty-src.conf <<EOF
deb-src http://ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe
EOF
apt-get update
apt-get build-dep <package name>
apt-get -b source <package name>
```

This may not work due to missing build dependencies; if so, repeat the last two commands for those commands.

You may wish to put this in a PPA, too.